# Multi Geocoder Here Api

Tags: here-api

I'm starting to develop an application to trace delivery routes.
But I need the lat and long addresses, and since Here has Geocoder and Routing, it's the best option.

But on their website they say it has batch geocoding, but I only find in the documentation the multi reverse geocoding, that's right, it does not have a multi geocoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is Batch Geocoder API. See details here: https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/quick-start.html

Answer (score 0):

Batch Geocoding is an asynchronous service for forward- *and* reversegeocoding up to 1mio addresses or coordinates in one batch, resp.

There is no forwardgeocoding equivalent for multi-reversegeocoding, such that that only option is to use Batch Geocoding for mass geocoding.